# Initial noise prior to square pulse

Tags: noise, ttl

I have a high voltage system (~5kV) to generate pulsed spark. I was able to detect the spark ignition. It has been shown in the images by the yellow line. This signal will be used to generate another signal with desired width (blue signal). The blue signal eventually will be sent to an instrument to turn the instrument on. The instrument expects a rising edge signal. But as it can be seen, there is a bump at the beginning of the blue signal, which causes error in triggering the instrument. I have been trying to use comparator, ferrite beads and schmitt trigger to reduce that bump. The images are after all the efforts. Can anyone direct me to smooth the initial bump on the blue signal?

Thank you.[image][image][image]

Comment: What are the specifications of the trigger input of the "instrument"? Please show a schematic of the circuit that you are using to create the trigger signal.

Comment: My guess would be that the yellow signal causes the bump on the blue signal. First test I would do is put them into two different scopes, to make sure that they aren't being linked by the scope itself.

Comment: Turn off your bandwidth limit, to see the real waveform. I see crosstalk between the Blue and the Yellow waveforms. Move wires around and see what changes. Either Electric Field (I = C * dV/dT) or Magnetic Field (Vinduced = 2e-7 * Area/Distance* dI/dT). Also, are you measuring with Coax Cables into the scope? or with high-voltage probes that have LONG LONG ground connections?

Comment: @ElliotAlderson: Thanks for the reply. The "instrument" requires a rapid rising edge voltage (which may or may not reach 5V).

Comment: @analogsystemsrf: Thanks for the reply. I am using coax cable. My entire circuit is on a breadboard and then taking a line to the scope coax cable. I suspect there might be some issues resulted by the breadboard.

Answer (score 2):

This 20 MHz resonance is due to your layout.

For example with wire being 10nH/cm and twisted pair being 40~50 pF/m

Hypothetically I can imagine your 20Mhz resonance caused by emissions, crosstalk pF and mutual inductance.  You can get this even with ground inductance from a 10MOhm 10:1 probe with a ground lead being 10cm long on a 1m coax.

suggestions

- Use twisted pair for all signals.
- use ferrite clamp around the arc paired wires or use coax.
- locate pairs or cables at right angles to minimize crosstalk.
- Use STP or shielded twisted pair.
- Lower the load impedance.
- add a LPF + xxMHz notch filter as a last resort.
- Keep supplies decoupled
- keep grounds clean with heavy braid.
- **minimize arc loop area.**